# Adding Additional Attributes to a ResponseBody Object

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have the following Spring `@RestController` method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPeople", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Person> getPeople(Model model){
    List<People> people = personRepo.getAllPeople();
    model.addAttribute("people", people);
    return people;
}
```

Which returns the following to the Response Body

```
[
    {"name":"Jim","group":1},
    {"name":"Dwight","group":2},
    {"name":"Stanley","group":3}
]
```

Can I modify this method (via the `@Controller` method itself, or with an AJAX request) to include additional attributes, both inside or outside of the `people` array, and without modifying the `Person` object - so that the object returned could look something like

```
{
    "people":[
        {"name":"Jim","group":1, "independentAttribute": "A"},
        {"name":"Dwight","group":2, "independentAttribute": "B"},
        {"name":"Stanley","group":3, "independentAttribute": "C"}
    ],
    "extraAttributes":[
        {"attribute1": 1,"attribute2": 2,"attribute3":3}
    ]
}
```

apologies if this isn't valid object/array syntax, lackadaisically threw it together.

Comment: _lackadaisically_ Fancy word.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm using FasterXML's JSON Processor

Comment: My mistake, it's a `@RestController` that returns the array to the Response Body - updated my question. Does that help?

Comment: Revised the ? again, I get the json object via an AJAX call using d3.json call (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json) - perhaps the object can be modified via an AJAX callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the object in the callback of the JSON request. I'm not familiar with d3_json but you can do something like

```
callback : function(data){
   //data is the returned List<Person> serialized to JSON
   var modifiedObj = new Object();
   modifiedObj.persons = data;
   modifiedObj.extraAttributes = [{"attribute1": 1,"attribute2": 2,"attribute3":3}]
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a custom JSON serializer, see this link: 
http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why you -1ed, did I misunderstand something? I thought you would like to add custom json string to the already serialized json (list of people)? Am I right?

Comment: I didn't downvote you m8. I found the answer helpful, although I've found @onepotato had what I was looking for

Comment: How would they use this JSON serializer?

Comment: Oh I see now, onepotato's solution is great, no probs :)